# How to make strcmp() work in my C program

Tags: c, string, pointers, strcmp

I am about to make an encryption of a textstring, using another textstring as a "key" for my encryption. It is basically just a reorganization of the ASCII-characters.

The key is given and is structured in a bad way, requiring some extra programming. The ASCII-characters are listed in this key with one charachter for each line, and the corresponding encrypted characters two indexes away.

This is the example of "key.txt":

```
A g
B 9
C ü
D (
E z
```

...continuing for all ASCII-characters. An encryption in my program would therfore result in:

```
"EDABEDA" -> "z(g9z(g"
```

When I am doing the encryption.

1. I let the program take in an input-string and I create another string with the encryption-key-characters.
2. I go through each character in the input string with a for-sling. For each character in the input string, I check if there is a matching character in my encryption-key string. In the encryption key I jump 4 steps at a time since I am going to encrypt and only have to compare A,B,C,D...
3. I use strcmp() to find a match. And when there is a match, when the character in the input string is the same as in the encryption key, I write the encrypted character to the output string. The encrypted character is placed two indexes ahead of the main character in the key-string.
4. The warnings occur in the strcmp()

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 3000

void encryption(char *input);

int main()
{
    char input[] = "EDABEDA";
    encryption(input);
}

void encryption(char *input)
{
    int length,i,k;
    size_t result;
    char dicc[1000];
    char output[SIZE];
    FILE *f;

    f = fopen("key.txt","r");

    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    result = fread(dicc, 1, length, f);

    int lenDic = strlen(dicc);
    int lenInp = strlen(input);

    for (i = 0 ; i < lenInp ; i++)
    {
        for (k = 4 ; k < lenDic ; k = k + 4)
        {
            if (strcmp(input[i],dicc[k]) == 0)
            {
                output[i] = dicc[k+2];
                printf("%c",output[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

I get the below warnings, and the program doesn't work. Anyone who can help me with this strcmp-warning and know how I should rearrange my program in order to meet its requirements?

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
if (strcmp(input[i],dicc[k]) == 0)
^
In file included from crypt.c:3:0:
/usr/include/string.h:144:12: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 extern int strcmp (const char *__s1, const char *__s2)
            ^
warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
if (strcmp(input[i],dicc[k]) == 0)
^
In file included from crypt.c:3:0:
/usr/include/string.h:144:12: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
extern int strcmp (const char *__s1, const char *__s2)
           ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `strcmp()` to compare strings, not characters. For your case this

```
if (input[i] == dicc[k])
```

should work.

Note that `char` is just an integer type not a string type, there is no string type in c. And one more thing, write safe code! Check of `fopen()` succeeded, and if `length` doesn't exceed `999`. Pretty much every thing that can be considered an error.

Comment: Thanks a million! And thanks for the tips on safe code!

Comment: In the encryption, I would like it to avoid to translate spaces and that they should be translated as just spaces. The spaces aren't included in the key.

When I put an "else if" statement under the if statement, stating: (input[i]=" ") then the output[i]=" ". And it gives me the same error as before. How to I implement this kind of condition?